# Checking if object exist in object array without looping

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I would like to check if my NSMutableArray contains my custom object. But if I understand correct contains functions searches for the same object in array (placed at the same memory point)

```
if(![objectArray containsObject:objToCheck])
{
    [objectArray addObject:objToCheck];
}
```

I know that objectArray has identical object with identical variable values compared to objToCheck, yet such if always returns false. Is there a way to check this without writing custom loop and comparing objects by their parameters?

Comment: Are you trying to find a specific object instance or an object that is a class member?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, NSSet might be more useful.

Comment: I'm trying to find specific object, all objects in list are same class, So I would like to find object with same variable values

Comment: You might look at using a temporary NSSet. This class is designed for quickly testing set membership. You can create one very easily with setWithArray:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the [`[NSObject isEqual:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a) method (actually it's part of the `NSObject` protocol) of your custom object and check whatever instance variables make sense to you for an object to be considered equal.

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectComparison.html) an Apple *Cocoa Competency* article on the subject.

Comment: ... and, as always, don't forget to override `hash` accordingly.

Comment: Would the default not simply use the object id?

Comment: @uchuugaka Yes the default implementation uses the object pointer to compare for equality; the OP however wants to use properties of the object itself to test for equality and this is where `-isEqual:` comes in.  And BTW that isn't the object's "id".

Comment: Well what I read was "is there a way to do this without checking by an object's parameters" which says to me something different.

Comment: @uchuugaka I don't understand why you would think that.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question mislead you. I just didn't want to write loop and compare each object by their parameters in that loop. Overriding isEqual method seems pretty clean solution.

Comment: Overriding isEqual: will indeed work but could also be a very limited case. Other scenarios may require comparison by other means. Special casing is fine if that is the only use case.

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a temporary NSSet from your array and testing against that for membership.

Comment: Probably because the NSSet does not help in comparing the objects. `NSArray`'s `containsObject:` can already check for membership. In this question it's the comparison that is missing.

Comment: NSSet membership is automatically unique object instances. NSArray can hold the same instance multiple times. Perhaps I've missed some angle in the problem.